# Stored procedure affecting multiple rows in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm running a database under the Marian engine and I have two tables:

```
Users(id, score)
Replies(user ID, reply)
```

Now I have to write a stored procedure that, given a number X, increments the field score by 1 for all the users that have replied with X.

How can I do that? I tried to do an update query, but MariaDB doesn't seem to work with the from clause.

Thanks in advance

Comment: edit the question with some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update query itself is straightforward:

```
UPDATE Users u
SET score = score + 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Replies r WHERE r.userID = u.id AND reply = 'X');
```

Inside a stored procedure, it might look like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE addScore (reply INT)
BEGIN
SET @query = 'UPDATE Users u
    SET score = score + 1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Replies r WHERE r.userID = u.id AND reply = ?)'

SET @x = reply;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @x;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```